Discordjs Interaction.followUp() not working
I'm making a discord bot command which returns members of a role. The interaction.deferReply() works fine but the interaction.followUp(...) doesn't work.
The interaction is stuck on '--- Bot is thinking...', and no errors messages are thrown.
I tried debugging my code using console.log to give me an idea of where my code is crashing, but it tells me everything's fine.
So I have no idea what's wrong
Heres the code,
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ActionRowBuilder, MessageButton } = require('@discordjs/builders')
const Data = require('../../data/data.json') // Data storage (Not used in this command)

Command Data
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('inrole')
        .setDescription('Retrieve members of a role.')
        .addRoleOption(option => 
            option.setName("role")
                .setDescription("Which role members to retrieve.")
                .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName("private")
                .setDescription("Send a private or public message?")
                .addChoices(
                    { name: 'Public', value: '1' },
                    { name: 'Private', value: '2' },)
        )
        .addIntegerOption(option =>
            option.setName("offset")
                .setDescription("Page offset, default is 0. Each page contains 10 users max.")
                .setMinValue(0)
        ),

Command Definition
    async execute(interaction, client) { // Function that defines the command
        await interaction.deferReply()
        let guild = interaction.guild;
        await guild.members.fetch()

        var role = guild.roles.cache.get(interaction.options.getRole('role').id)

        var p = interaction.options.getString("private")
        if (p == '2') p = true; else p = false

        var n = interaction.options.getInteger("offset") ?? 0


        var mList = role.members.map(x => '<@' + x.id + '> ||' + x.username + '||').slice(n*10,n*10+10).join('\n')

        if ((mList === "") && n > 0) {
            mList = "Page is empty."
        } else if (mList === "") {
            mList = "No one has this role."
        }

        let len = role.members.map(x => '<@' + x.id + '> ||' + x.username + '||').slice(n*10,n*10+10).length
        mList = '-# Page: ' + (Number(n) + 1) + ' | Showing ' + len + ' member' + (len != 1 ? 's' : '') + '\n** **\n' + mList + "\n** **"

        var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Users in the `' + role.name + '` role')
            .setDescription(mList)
            .setFooter({text: 'Total Members: ' + role.members.size})
        
        await interaction.followUp({embeds: [embed],ephemeral: p})
   }
}

Any ideas? Thanks.
Update: This also happens to every other command my bot has, including simple ones like /ping or /coinflip, but chat commands using prefixes work.
2nd Update: It works sometimes, and doesn't sometimes.

Do you have the guild members intent enabled? Your bot may be getting stuck on fetching members if the intent is not enabled

Yea I do, both in the dashboard and the code.

interaction.deferReply() allows you to postpone the response for your actions. It does not return a message. To submit your response, try editReply instead of followUp.
For more information, please visit:
https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html#deferred-responses
